# What does it mean for regression to the mean to "work backward in time"?

Tags: regression

Please see the emboldened phrase below.

> Then the hammer drops. The triumph of mediocrity observed by Secrist,
> Hotelling points out, is more or less automatic whenever we study a variable
> that’s affected by both stable factors and the influence of chance. Secrist’s
> hundreds of tables and graphs “prove nothing more than that the ratios in
> question have a tendency to wander about.” The result of Secrist’s exhaustive
> investigation is “mathematically obvious from general considerations, and
> does not need the vast accumulation of data adduced to prove it.” Hotelling
> drives his point home with a single, decisive observation. Secrist believed the
> regression to mediocrity resulted from the corrosive effect of competitive
> forces over time; competition was what caused the top stores in 1916 to be
> hardly above average in 1922. But what happens if you select the stores with
> the highest performance in 1922? As in Galton’s analysis, these stores are
> likely to have been both lucky and good. If you turn back the clock to 1916,
> whatever intrinsic good management they possess should still be in force, but
> their luck may be totally different. Those stores will typically be closer to
> mediocre in 1916 than in 1922. In other words, if regression to the mean
> were, as Secrist thought, the natural result of competitive forces, **those forces
> would have to *work backward in time as well as forward.***
>       Hotelling’s review is polite but firm, distinctly more in sorrow than in
> anger: he is trying to explain to a distinguished colleague, in the kindest way
> possible, that he has wasted ten years of his life. But Secrist didn’t take the
> hint. The issue after next of JASA ran his contentious letter of response,
> pointing out a few misapprehensions in Hotelling’s review, but otherwise
> spectacularly missing the point. Secrist insisted once again that the regression
> to mediocrity was not a mere statistical generality, but rather was particular to
> “data affected by competitive pressure and managerial control.” At this point
> Hotelling stops being nice and lays it out straight. “The thesis of the book,” he
> writes in response, “when correctly interpreted, is essentially trivial. . . . To
> ‘prove’ such a mathematical result by a costly and prolonged numerical study
> of many kinds of business profit and expense ratios is analogous to proving
> the multiplication table by arranging elephants in rows and columns, and then
> doing the same for numerous other kinds of animals. The performance, though
> perhaps entertaining, and having a certain pedagogical value, is not an important contribution either to zoölogy or mathematics.”

Ellenberg, *How Not to Be Wrong* (2014), pages 307-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hotelling's point is that both these features not only happened but should have been expected to happen:

- leading stores in 1916 more often than not became closer to the average in 1922 than they had been in 1916
- leading stores in 1922 more often than not had been closer to the average in 1916 than they became in 1922

so *regression to the mean* happened forward in time for the 1916 leading stores but backward in time for the 1922 leading stores.

There was nothing new in this:  Galton's original studies had shown that the children of extremely tall parents tended to be closer to the average height than their parents were, leading to the use of the word "regression" for the analysis which showed this; Galton then showed with the same data that the parents of extremely tall children tended to be closer to the average height than their children were.  One of his 1875 charts, [copied from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Galton#/media/File:Galton%27s_correlation_diagram_1875.jpg), looked like this

[image]